# PHP MySQL group by similar values in a column

Tags: php, mysql

i am try to develop a functionality to group messages stored in mysql table. Every column here references the all the parents. It looks something like this:

```
 Subject        Message Id    References  
 ----------------------------------------
 Message 1          1             1
 Message 2          2             1,2
 Message 3          3             1,2,3
 Message 4          4             4
```

What I would like to do here is group all the messages based on their references. This table structure is a result of php imap mails. The references point to the parent. And hence I would like to group the messages based on references. I would like to show grouped messages in the frontend instead of showing individual messages. I would like to iterate through groups and show the frontend users something like this.

```
 Groups      Subject               Count       
 ---------------------------------------------
 Group 1     Message 1               3
             Message 2
             Message 3
 Group 2     Message 4               1
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: Your explanation is not clear.  How are the groups defined?  Why do your desired results have four rows, but two of them have blank values in `Column1`?

Comment: Sorry but your example really does not convey what you're trying to do. What is the grouping criteria?

Comment: Group by similar values isn't easy, I reckon you've a problem with database design here, first and foremost.

But if you want to get certain values, you can do string operations on column2, select the results into a temporary table, and then do your grouping there.  

This approach would probably work for your problem, altho you haven't clearly articulated what you need done.

Comment: I have updated my question. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Start by sharing your table structure and the queries you're currently using.

Comment: @ChintanParekh, don't worry, what its giving in result? when you use group by your expected column name ?

Comment: First step, normalise you database design. move the references values onto a separate table with one row per message per reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearest I can get to what I think you want would be this:-

```
SELECT CONCAT('Group ', Sub1.group_order), GROUP_CONCAT(Subject), COUNT(*)
FROM Messages
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(References, ',', 1) AS iRef, @Order:=@Order+1 as group_order
    FROM Messages, (SELECT @Order:=0)
    ORDER BY iRef
) Sub1
ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(Messages.References, ',', 1) = Sub1.iRef
GROUP BY CONCAT('Group ', Sub1.group_order)
```

Although this is producing one row per group (concatenating all the subjects together - easy enough to split in your script).

This assumes that you are only interested in the first element in the reference column (which seems to be the case in the example data you gave) and that the group number is just a sequential number.